# setsockopt() get EBADF in mmaped netlink

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, netlink

Im trying to use memory map I/O netlink to transfer bulk packets from kernel to user space, and I followed a guide document from Patrick McHardy [1](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netlink_mmap.txt). However, when I try to setup the shared ring buffer in user space by using:

```
setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_NETLINK, NETLINK_RX_RING, &req, sizeof(req));

setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_NETLINK, NETLINK_TX_RING, &req, sizeof(req));
```

Both functions return -1, and the errno is 1, which means the descriptor is invalid. Im confused about that because I also referred to many other source codes and they can setup the ring successfully.

My code is almost the same as Patrick's [1](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netlink_mmap.txt):

```
int sock_fd = -1;
sock_fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_DECODE);
if (sock_fd < 0)
    return -1;

bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&src_addr, sizeof(src_addr));

/* init the mmap buffer */
unsigned int block_size = 16 * getpagesize();
struct nl_mmap_req req = {
        .nm_block_size      = block_size,
        .nm_block_nr        = 64,
        .nm_frame_size      = 16384,
        .nm_frame_nr        = 64 * block_size / 16384,
};

/* Configure ring parameters */
if (setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_NETLINK, NETLINK_RX_RING, &req, sizeof(req)) < 0){
    if(errno > 0)
        printf("%d\n", errno);
}
if (setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_NETLINK, NETLINK_TX_RING, &req, sizeof(req)) < 0){
    if(errno > 0)
        printf("%d", errno);
    exit(1);
}
```

This code is built in Ubuntu 14.04, and kernel version is 3.13.0-74-generic.

Anyone idea about it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Value 1 of `errno` is `EPERM`, which means that you have insufficient priviledges for perfom operation.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Oh, thanks for your help. I understand what happen in my code now.